# Regex string for validating Decimal excluding zero

Tags: c#, regex

I have a function which creates Regex string for validating decimal.

```
public static string DecimalWithPlaces(int wholePart, int fractionalPart)
{
     return @"^-?[0-9]{0," + wholePart + @"}\.[0-9]{1," + fractionalPart + @"}$";
}
```

Could anyone let me know how can I excluding zero from this?

For example: "0", "0.0","0.00" etc should not be matched.

Thanks

Comment: @Amy - I think you should post a code example as an answer, as that's much better than doing RegEx.  RegEx is useful, but too many developers (IMO) turn to it when there are simpler (and more readable/maintainable) ways to accomplish their goals.

Comment: You may just add a negative lookahead in the beginning of your expression `(?!0+(?:\.0+)?)`

Comment: Why are you "validating decimal"? What are you going to be doing with it? Performing arithmetic? Arithmetic on valid decimals can be invalid. Storing it in a database? Databases can reject valid decimals. I smell an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: Doing this as a regex seems strange. Why not just use `Double.TryParse()` and then compare to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amy's right - examples would be good.

However, I'm going in blind.

Did you want to exclude all zeros, or just the value of zero?

To exclude zeros, try this and see what happens.

```
public static string DecimalWithPlaces(int wholePart, int fractionalPart)
{
    return @"^-?[1-9]{0," + wholePart + @"}\.[1-9]{1," + fractionalPart + @"}$";
}
```

To exclude the number zero... That's actually not a good check for regex. That's a value check.

In my books you should be using TWO validation steps on the value. One to check that it meets your precision/scale requirements as per your regex above, the second to then check it for nonzero value.

I do believe that using regex for the zero value thing is possible. But I strongly advise against it. That said, if you're committed to ignoring that reccomendation then you'll probably want to look into [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex structures.

Comment: This won't catch numbers like 0.9 or 25.0, etc.

Comment: I misread the question on my first readthrough - thought that was what was wanted. Quickly edited to provide extra info. Think you just missed my edit by about a minute.

Comment: Ignores group separators... I really would like to give you upvote for effort, but getting regex that acceptable parses decimal/float values is painful - not sure if going for correct one or advising against is right approach to make the answer better...